# Vote Early, Vote Often (Seriously)

Tags: discussion

I’ll start by echoing the message from other sites that went through beta, voting helps us define the scope of the site and figure out who the experts are. To quote the [Vote early, vote often blog post:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

> Putting voting front and center is very much intentional; it is how good content is voted to the top wrong or incorrect content is voted
>   to the bottom users who consistently provide useful content accrue
>   reputation and are granted more privileges on the site It’s only
>   through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can
>   emerge to help run and govern the site. Voting is how site leadership
>   forms. That’s why the reputation leagues show a breakdown of
>   reputation spectrums.

---

As someone who has been through private betas before, I can’t stress how important this is now and throughout the site especially in the early days. Every vote up or down will help shape the site and that shaping will be so much amplified in the first few days as the first real questions and answers pour in. Users will look at highly voted questions and answer not only as good information, but as examples of what answers and questions should look like on the site. Users will also go to the meta and see how the community feels about topics and ideas related to running the site because of voting done on the meta.   It’s the most important aspect of the site and will be the biggest contributes you can make to it.

Also, please keep in mind when voting that your votes are yours. You don't have to up or down vote something just because others have. Read it, make your decision about the content, and vote accordingly.

Happy Voting.

Answer (score 12):

> Also, please keep in mind when voting that your votes are yours. You
>   don't have to up or down vote something just because others have. Read
>   it, make your decision about the content, and vote accordingly.

Echoing importance of taking **your own** decision on voting after reading the question / answer / discussion  and not because others have voted, I have seen these kinds of things during other sites' private beta.

Also please post questions that are meaningful and within the scope and not too broad, show some research. Don't just ask questions like:

- What is the meaning of ..?
- What is your opinion on ..?

Let's ask, vote and participate to make this site go through graduation.

Answer (score 8):

Coming from a small (and with respect to voting a rather stingy) community (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)  I would to reinforce the importance of voting - not only in private beta but even more so during public beta and towards graduation.

Gaining new users and turning them into active community members is significantly supported by StackExchange's gamification system, reputation based on votes and the badges that come along. So up-voting encourages new users and is thus part of a welcoming community and a growth of the site. Fishing for enthusiastic new users and knowledgeable experts will be key for the success of this branch of SE especially given the wide variety of IoT devices out there.

Commenting and/or discussions in chat and meta significantly add to the power of votes. Especially when downvoting please consider to comment what exactly you feel is wrong with the question and how it could be improved and made be more on-topic.